# Word for someone talking about something as if he understands it when he doesn't

Tags: word-choice

Not someone overstepping boundaries, but if, for example, I was at Jiffy Lube and suggested different things as if I knew anything about cars.

Ideally (though I know it's a long shot) I'd want a word I could use when I caught myself doing it (i.e. not super derogatory, but acknowledging the social gaffe).

> Sorry, I don't actually know anything about cars; I'm just [being a] __.

Comment: This phenomenon is closely related to the [Dunning-Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: The first word that comes to mind is ***politician***, though I realise that’s more of an example than a definition. ;-)

Comment: See http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/904 about including mildly offensive jokes in comments.

Comment: It sounds like you're *talking out of your ass*.

Comment: Bull shitting....?

Comment: @WS2, Yeah, "BS-ing" was my first instinct.  That almost seems intentional, though.

Comment: @calvin I don't think BS is intentional, I know plenty (mainly men) who do it all the time without apparently being aware of it.

Comment: @Mynamite May I ask your gender?  I may refer you to GEdgar's comment.  :P  Jkjk.  You make a good point.

Comment: @calvin I deliberately chose a neutral name, people can make of that what they will. In any case, it wasn't meant to be a joke, it's an observation! If it makes people feel better there are traits I consider mainly women to have which are equally annoying. And that goes for all the [other genders](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/02/15/the-complete-glossary-of-facebook-s-51-gender-options.html) too....

Answer (score 2):

Not one word but there is an idiomatic phrase:

> **[talk through one's hat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk_through_one%27s_hat)**
>
> **1.** (idiomatic) To speak lacking expertise, authority, or knowledge; to invent or fabricate facts.
>
> **2.** (idiomatic) To assert something as true or valid; to bluff.

Thus, bluffing somewhat has this sense also.

---

There is another similar idiom but it has other connotations as well:

> [whistle in the dark](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whistle_in_the_dark): (idiomatic, US) To speak of something despite having little knowledge of it.

Answer (score 2):

A [know-it-all](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/know-it-all) is a person who acts as though he or she had better knowledge or understanding than anyone else. It is a hard thing to admit to being, but it *is* a term for someone who pretends to knowledge he doesn't have.

Once, my husband and I heard someone apologize for being a know-it-all by saying, **and now I've said far more than I actually know about the subject**. We thought it a humorous way to admit to the fault, and it became a family joke.

Comment: I like that.  I think I'll use it, too.

Comment: A "know-it-all" person may actually know things and talks/interrupts too much when it comes to the things that he knows. More like a smartass, a pretentious person. I think this sense is more common. Isn't it?

Comment: @ermanen - A know-it-all can be arrogant or obnoxious as well, but not necessarily. I do like your idiom, though. The OP asked for a word, and that was the closest I could get.

Answer (score 0):

Prententious,  ostentatious are adjectives that point out such behavior.